# Eclipse switches @ and "

Tags: eclipse

Once every few hours this happens - when I press *Shift-2* to get a `"`, and `@` appears. When I press *Shift-'* it puts in a `"` (although this only appears after pushing another key as well). I am on an English (as opposed to American) keyboard. I must be pressing some sort of shortcut key combination, but I don't know what it is. It goes away when I restart Eclipse. I can live with this problem, but I would rather not!

Anyone know what the shortcut I'm accidentally using is, so I can avoid it/correct it in future?

Edit: Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several language layouts on the computer you are probably switching on them.

What OS are you using?
If Windows 7 the shortcut is ctrl + shift
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/10444-63-shortcut-keys-keyboard-language-changing

If you're using windows XP i think the shortcut was alt + shift

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 but alt + shift did it for me. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, pressing Ctrl + Shift changes keyboard layouts. In your case it seems to Switch to the US layout which has the @ on Shift + 2